# Uploading images/videos also uses net bandwidth limit in Cloudinary?

Tags: bandwidth, cloudinary, transcoding

I am looking forward to using Cloudinary for my present project. And cloudinary recently added proper support for videos, which is god-send.

I am a little confused about the bandwidth limit:

Will the net bandwidth limit imposed by Cloudinary be effected by the uploading of content (image/videos)? Or is it only applicable while I view (download) them?

Also, does Cloudinary charge the developer for automatic transcoding of videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudinary only charges bandwidth for downloading content from your account.

Regarding video transformations, Cloudinary charges for each newly transformed video according to the following policy:

For SD videos every second equals 2 transformations,
While for HD videos it equals as 4.

Comment: Transformations I get. But every raw video I upload to cloudinary will be automatically transcoded on their end, so that if its a 100mb raw video, it gets stored as 50-60mb using the required sampling rate etc. Is this charged too?

Comment: @ketanbhatt, Videos are not being transcoded at all if it's not explicitly asked for (e.g., incoming transformations, eager transformations, etc.).

Having said that, for every video upload Cloudinary charges for Transformations, as part of our charging policy.